# How to prove that the socket connection timeout occurs within 60 seconds?

Tags: java, http, google-app-engine, timeout

I know that the socket timeout for fetching URLs is fixed on 60 seconds.

I use `java.util.logging` and before I call the `https` function I log this:

*2012-03-27 14:46:15.445 TelenorClient changeSimStatus: attempt 1 ....*

And the exception occurs 5 seconds later

*2012-03-27 14:46:20.197 TelenorClient changeSimStatus: exception java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout while fetching: https://serviceportal...*

I am using a JAX-WS based webservice client, and setting the timeout using the BindingProviderProperties and RequestContext is not allowed, according to this message:

*com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.BindingProviderProperties is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment*

Which corresponds with the first statement that Google App Engine has its own way of setting the timeout. But again, to me, it seems much shorter than 60 seconds.

I am looking for tips on how to address this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL Fetch service (used by your JAX-WS client) is [limited to 5 seconds timeout](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview#Requests). You can extend it to max 60 seconds via `setConnectTimeout()`. For more (up to 10 min) you must execute it via Task Queue or Cron.

**Update:**

If youR JAX-WS client does not give you access to connection, than you can try executing the whole JAX-WS call on the task queue. This is easiest done via [`DeferredTask`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505116/java-gae-deferredtask-example).

Comment: Thanks Peter for the answer, can you maybe show where in the jax-ws framework I can call setConnectTimeout() ?

Comment: Hi peter, I am facing issue with connection timeout. I have configured 10 sec ,but  its still taking more than 1 mins. Can you please advise something here? I have configured using spring XML context.

Answer (score 2):

I got this tip from Mitch Rudominer; just use the text values of the constants.

```
Map<String, Object> context = ((BindingProvider) service).getRequestContext();
context.put("com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout", 60*1000);
context.put("com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout", 10*1000);
```

It looks like it is working:

> 2012-07-03 14:26:**45**.604
>   com.simservices.bus.kpndata.DataDetailsServlet getDetailData:
>   2012-04-01 - 8931084711061420005
>
> 2012-07-03 14:26:**56**.183
>   com.simservices.bus.kpndata.DataDetailsServlet getDataUsage: getting
>   the response for data from KPN
>
> 2012-07-03 14:27:**33**.619
>   com.simservices.bus.kpndata.DataDetailsServlet getDataUsage:
>   detailsList has 4612 elements
>
> 2012-07-03 14:27:**36**.540
>   com.simservices.bus.kpndata.DataDetailsServlet getDataUsage: added
>   4612 data elements

Comment: For the development server, the keys appear to be "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout" and "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout". (Source: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ads-java/source/diff?spec=svn8cc64e117a4317801cefadfdb0f8457c2d9b47d6&r=8cc64e117a4317801cefadfdb0f8457c2d9b47d6&format=side&path=/modules/ads_lib_appengine/src/main/java/com/google/api/ads/common/lib/soap/jaxws/JaxWsHandler.java)