# How to serve CPU intensive webservice requests in the cloud?

Tags: web-services, google-app-engine, concurrency, cloud, rackspace

**Background:** I'm running a webservice in which each request involves a fair amount of computations (up to 10 seconds on a quadcore machine).

Each request can be broken down to about 150 independent (and equally small) subtasks.

**What I'm after:** l'm looking for a hosting service that allows me to serve these kinds of requests efficiently in a scalable manner.

**What I've considered:** I've looked into Google App Engine and Rackspace.

It seems to me as if GAE is intended for simple requests, requiering litte resources to process. Problem with something like Rackspace is that I can't tell in advance how many vCPUs I may need (and even if I knew how big future spikes would be, I don't want to sit with, say, 40 servers idling the rest of the time)

**Questions:**

1. Would it be possible to use GAE in the following way:

   1. For each request, split it up into 150 subtasks
   2. Process all subtasks independently by doing 150 concurrent HTTP requests to the same webapp (but through a differrnt method)
   3. Collect the results from the "subresults" and return a response to the original request.
2. Is there any possibility that Map Reduce for GAE could be of any help?
3. Is there any other service better suited for this task?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, this is possible. The usual way would be to use [Task Queue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview), possibly via [DeferredTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505116/java-gae-deferredtask-example) helper class.

   1.3 Normal web requests (to frontend instances) are limited to 30s, so doing this in synchronous way is not guaranteed to succeed. Also note that instances are artificially limited to do 10 parallel requests (if multithreading is enabled).
2. Yes, this is a job for [map reduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/). But note that map reduce is async - you give it tasks to do and it will be done sometime in the future.
3. Given the processing you need you might want to look at [GAE backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview) (they are long running with [multithrading](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager) and come in [different sizes](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/backends#Instance_Classes)). If you need even more processing power, then you might want to look at [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute-engine).

Answer (score 0):

Unless all of these 150 subtasks are read-only activities, trying to run them all in a single thread is just not safe.  Web requests are unreliable - people can cancel, hit refresh if it takes too long, close windows in the middle, or just time out due to network issues.  The background HTTP requests, likewise, can have a whole mess of problems.  The standard solution is to have your front-end code simply build a list of things that need to be done, so it can get back to the user quickly, and have a back-end 'worker' process handle the (potentially unreliable) subtasks.  Depending on what your application is doing, you might bounce the user to a "working" screen (like searching for airfare) where they can **safely** wait for the results to come up, or it might just be stuffed away as a "pending" job (like ordering something from Amazon).

There's countless different ways to handle this basic workflow.  If you stick with Google App Engine, they have a "task queue" as [part of the platform](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) - providing a simple mechanisms for creating & dispatching background tasks.  If you go with Rackspace, their cloud offering is less of a unified platform so you'll have to either roll your own queue or get one to plug into your setup.