# Cannot create Timer class in backend AppEngine instance...why?

Tags: google-app-engine, timer

I am able to create threads however creation of a Timer and scheduling it are eluding me. I am unsure why this is failing...and silently!

Any ideas?

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: Make sure you create threads via Google provided ThreadManager: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager

Answer (score 0):

You can use threads in GAE, but there are limitations:

1. You must create them via GAE provided [`ThreadManager`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager).
2. On frontend instances threads can not outlive requests. This means that Timer started from a http request can not run TimerTask if the request already ended - I guess this is why it silently fails.

If you need to start a delayed task, try using [DeferredTask](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/DeferredTask) ([here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505116/java-gae-deferredtask-example)) with [ETA setting](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions#etaMillis%28long%29http://).

Comment: I already have threading abstractions in my application which for AppEngine servers create threads in this manner. I have exposed backend to user requests so this has nothing to do with frontend. Perhaps they aren't creating Timers using appropriate threading API...if there are no changes to JRE then I guess this is the case.

Comment: Dang...it appears Thread.sleep is a no-go...kind of hard to roll your own timer. I am not seeing option in queue classes for simulating scheduling of thread.